# Параллельный запуск плейбука ansible в режиме serial: 1

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, ansible

**Дано**:

- 10 компьютерных классов с +/- 10 компьютерами.
- В каждый класс заходит аплинк на 100мбит. На этаж - гигабит.
- Образ на 180 ГБ в формате CloneZilla.
- Известны хостнеймы, прописаны в `inventory.ini`.

  - Каждый класс в своей группе: `[1403]`, `[1405]` и т.д.

**Что надо**:

- Раскидать образ на каждый компьютер.
- Управление разворачиванием осуществить через ansible (v2.7.6 + ubuntu 16.04).
- В каждом классе одновременно не должно быть запущено больше **одного** действующего деплоя. Остальные машины - в режиме ожидания подтверждения.

**Что не получается**:

- Указание `serial: 1` не помогает. Разворачивается только один компьютер из всего `inventory.ini`.
- Указание `serial: 10` не помогает. Разворачиваются первые 10 машин из списка, как будто он не разделён группами.

**Плейбук, который работает не так, как хочется**:

```
---
  - name: Run CloneZilla
    hosts: all
    strategy: linear
    serial:
      - 1
    vars:
      filename_rx_end: end-of-rx-label
    tasks:

    - name: Run CloneZilla deploy (send "yes" + Enter)
      when: ansible_system == 'Linux'
      block:
        - command: sudo screen -x -X stuff 'y^M'
        - local_action:
            module: uri
            url: 'http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ filename_rx_end }}'
          register: result
          until: result.status == 200
          retries: 10000
          delay: 10
```

### Главный вопрос:

Как сделать так, чтобы одновременно `sudo screen -x -X stuff 'y^M'` был послан только на `1403-01`, `1405-01`, `1407-01` и т.д.? Затем на `1403-02`, `1405-02`, `1407-02` и т.д.

**Возможный костыль**:

Запустить отдельную сессию `tmux`, создать 10 терминалов и в каждом запустить плейбук с отдельным инвентарем. Но не хочется.

**Как было раньше**:

Всё запускалось одновременно и неспешно тянулось несколько суток. На некоторых этапах - невозможно предсказать хорошо ли получился конкретный компьютер или надо переделывать.

или

Выпадание одного компа в самой первой версии - означало перезапуск всего этажа.

Comment: Не хочу перепечатывать ответ – посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670007/2795592 – либо запатчить Ansible, либо формировать инвентарь специальным образом.

Comment: Нет, количество хостов разное. :( В общем - штатными ванильными средствами на данный момент невозможно. Ок, вполне сойдёт за ответ.

Comment: Оформи короткий ответ со ссылкой на большой SO, я помечу как правильный.

Comment: Не пробовали разбить на части, использовать  `rsync` или развернуть локальную пиринговую сеть (torrent) добавив все хосты (100) в сидеры и создав 1-2 раздающих сервера?

Comment: сервер: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/torrentserver и можно задиплоить на клиенты `rtorrent`

Comment: @Hellseher, как через торрент кидать архив блочного устройства? Я в курсе про https://github.com/tjjh89017/ezio, но осилить не смог - экспы не хватило.

Comment: @donRumata Если нужно сконфигурированный сервера в большом масштабе с "железного ноля" (Windows? раз размер 150ГБ) есть смысл развернуть  PXE сервер или использовать Clonzilla Server Edition https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/. Я первым делом развернул сервер провизии на PXE со списком начальных загрузок Debian netinstall (200MB на всю ос) потом уже допиливаю Ansible. Пропускная способность 20 серверов в час от 0 до полной конфигурации. Есть из коробки решение тоже https://www.theforeman.org/

Comment: @Hellseher, pxe - основной способ деплоя всего чего мне надо. Давно настроен и нормально пашет. Правда кроме EFI, но это - отдельный разговор. CloneZilla SE была в самом начале: https://juick.com/don-Rumata/1163953. Я потом от этой идеи отказался, т.к. смотри самый-самый конец вопроса. Возможно когда-нибудь вернусь, но пока - unicast рулит. И да. Мне надо НЕ линукс раскатывать - с seed и kickstart проблем вроде как не встречал. Мне винду - с софтом и кучей прокликанных штук.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я победил проблему. Технически выглядит коряво, но работает уже 2 массовых деплоя. Наверняка это можно выразить более красиво, но пока хотя бы пруф оф концепт. Итак:

Основные моменты: комбинируем `serial` и порядок хостов в inventory-файле.

Есть 1 inventory файл со списком компов и 3 аудиториями:

```
[1404]
1404-01
# 1404-02
1404-03
1404-04
1404-05
# 1404-06
1404-07
1404-08
1404-09
1404-10
1404-11
1404-12
1404-13
1404-14
1404-15
1404-16
1404-17
1404-18
# 1404-19
[1405]
1405-01
1405-02
1405-03
1405-04
1405-05
1405-06
1405-07
1405-08
1405-09
1405-10
[1406]
1406-01
1406-02
1406-03
1406-04
1406-05
1406-06
1406-07
1406-08
1406-09
1406-10
1406-11
1406-12
1406-13
```

Есть bash-скрипт, который вычисляет сколько у нас первых компов, сколько вторых и т.д. А затем - формирует столбик цифр, которые надо прописать в этот самый [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size):

```
PATH_TO_SH="/data/sh"
PATH_TO_INVENTORY=$(echo "$PATH_TO_SH"/ansible/playbooks/inventory/ecc)

MIN_NUMBER_COMPUTERS="1"
MAX_NUMBER_COMPUTERS="20"

INI_FILE_4_CALC="ecc-clonezilla.ini"

cd "$PATH_TO_INVENTORY"

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/11891206
# Формируем в цикле номера, которые совпадают (потому что я так задал хостнеймы) с порядковым номером компьютеров в аудиториях. Т.е. "01, 02, 03..20".
for i in $(seq -w "$MIN_NUMBER_COMPUTERS" "$MAX_NUMBER_COMPUTERS")
    do
    # sort'ируем по 2-рому столбцу (у нас же схема "кабинет-номер компа"), используя разделитель "-" | убираем "grep -v" назависимо от регистра "-i" все строки, которые содержат "#" и "[" | считаем количество строк, и добавляем пробелов и "-", потому что синтаксис yaml и вот это всё.
    sort -t - -k 2 "$INI_FILE_4_CALC" | grep -E -v -i '(#|\[)' | grep "\-$i" | wc -l | sed 's/^/      - /'
done
```

В результате получаем такое:

```
  - 3
  - 2
  - 3
  - 3
  - 3
  - 2
  - 3
  - 3
  - 3
  - 3
  - 2
  - 2
  - 2
  - 1
  - 1
  - 1
  - 1
  - 1
  - 0
  - 0
```

Список соответствует: первых компов у нас 3, вторых у нас 2 (закамеченные сломались\украли\испарились), третьих 3. Под конец - по одному и ну и нули как забивка. Выхлоп пишем в `serial:`, т.е. руками правим плейбук.

Сам inventory (можно положить рядом с оригинальным) тоже должен быть отсортирован через `sort -t - -k 2 "$INI_FILE_4_CALC" | grep -E -v -i '(#|\[|^$)'`.

После всей этой магии схема отлично отработала на 120+ машинах 3 (выше писал, что 2. 3-й раз - работа над ошибками) раза.

**Замечание 1.** Важно понимать, что код алгоритма вычисления прибит гвоздями к способу именования хостов и заранее известному максимальному количеству обрабатываемх машин. Если ваша схема как-то отличается - тупой копипаст примера не отработает.

**Замечание 2.**

Схема

```
serial:
  - "{{ serial_for_run_deploy.stdout_lines }}"
```

не работает. Ансибл сразу хочет знать сколько в какой последовательности запускать. Внутрь таска serail тоже не пихается.

P.S. С НГ всех!

Answer (score 2):

Тривиальными средствами это не сделать.

Если есть возможность запатчить Ansible или в разных группах одинаковое количество хостов – есть решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670007/2795592

Comment: Я решил проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Всё свелось к костылю в виде `tmux`. В принципе - можно отдельно смотреть каждую группу независимо от общего процесса. Хотя первый запуск всего этого - немного дольше по времени.