# Установить и запустить Windows 10, не используя BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-10, hdd, bios, ssd

Имею ноутбук с HDD и SSD. На HDD стоит Windows 10. SSD выбрать загрузочным нельзя. Можно ли перенести файлы системы Windows на SSD, оставив загрузочный раздел на HDD? Чтобы при попытке загрузки с HDD, он ссылался на систему, которая лежит на SSD.

Comment: При загрузке bios нажми F8 -  должно появиться меню выбора источника загрузки. Если там не будет ssd, то скорее всего надо смотреть настройки bios. А как вы предложили так вроде никто не делает.

Comment: Он предлагает три варианта: USB, HDD/SSD, LAN. Если выбрать второе - то грузится с HDD. Если через флешку ставить винду на SSD, то при загрузке он будет грузится с HDD и выдавать что ничего нету. Т.е. биос не отображает SSD и грузиться с него не хочет, т.к. с завода он использовался как кэш. А я хочу установить на него систему. Для этого я придумал схему: говорим биосу грузиться с HDD, а HDD будет грузить систему с SSD. Только вот как правильно это сделать я не знаю. Есть такие системы как PrimeOS (на осн.Android), которые можно из под винды установить на любой диск, и будет DualBoot.

Comment: Вынь хдд, поставь систему на ссд, вставь обратно хдд

Comment: HDD стоит 2,5", а SSD через отдельный m.2 NGGF type B. Оба SATA3. И даже если сделать так ты советуешь, BIOS не увидит SSD, грузиться с него не станет, будет писать что система не найдена.

Comment: Думаю сделать через Boot Manager на HDD ссылку на SSD.

Comment: Сделать можно, но раз ты пришёл сюда с таким вопросом, то я поддержу @Talleyran. Просто переустанови. Активация не слетит и файлики останутся на месте. Выстрелить себе в ногу в таком случае - ОЧЕНЬ трудно.

Comment: @Hugo Khrapov, какой у вас ноутбук? Скорее всего со второго диска грузится можно, но в режиме UEFI

Answer (score 1):

Вот алгоритм действий:

- Скачайте программу установщик ОС (Ссылок давать не буду, их можно найти на любом сайте по запросу "Установка Windows 10 без BIOS").
- Извлеките установщик из архива.
- Запустите его. Установите ОС. (На диске должно быть не меньше 30-40 ГБ)

Старая Windows у Вас останется, но Вы сможете ее удалить вручную. Но я бы использовал BIOS чтоб не морочить себе мозги

Comment: Ну я админ\билд инженер. В программировании почти не шарю, но чё-нить настроить - пожалуйста. И я тут сижу именно, чтобы отвечать на подобные вопросы.

Comment: @donRumata Ну я знаю способ только с помощью программы-установщика. Ответьте вы, я как раз расширю кругозор.

Comment: Я выше написал что бы я сделал на месте автора. Мой камент касался больше "Не спрашивайте у программистов". По поводу "на любом сайте по запросу": майки с 2014 (первого релиза w10) выкладывают винду у себя на сайте, никуда лазить не надо. По поводу способов "как ставить винду": лично мне нравится такой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937143/191416. Но особенностей установки там даже не на статью, а на целую вики. Зато некоторые проблемы исчезают (но появляются другие, хехе).

Comment: Если вам кажется, что вопрос не по теме - поднимайте соответствующую тревогу. Не следует так снисходительно отправлять человека в поисковики и другие места. Тем более, что вы и сами здесь не так давно. В любом случае, к ответу данный абзац не относился, так что пришлось его убрать.

Answer (score 0):

А теперь по существу. Чтобы в BIOS нормально выбирался нужный диск надо выключить secure boot и переключить режим загрузки с uefi на  legacy. Дальше спокойно менять местами любые устройства.

Или ставить начисто в режиме uefi с вынутым hdd, из официального образа майкрософт, как я уже описал в комментарии. Тогда при установке система сама пропишет в биос нужную точку монтирования.

Или перенести 10-ку с одного диска на другой вместе с загрузочным разделом и чтобы не слетела лицензия умеет Acronis True Image. В виде iso, записанного на флэшку он ничего не спрашивает про лицензию, только тссс. Если в этом случае физически поменять диски местами, то больше можно вообще ничего не трогать.

Или, если после установки/копирования на другой диск загрузка все равно не происходит, запуститься все с того же диска винды (флэшки с официальным iso) в режиме восстановления и сказать, что есть проблема с загрузкой. Есть шанс, что утилита восстановления починит mbr и все заработает. Мне так помогало на некоторых капризных устройствах.

UPD. Если ваш SSD в формфакторе PCIe карточки, то скорее всего ни Acronis ни другая программа из под Bios его не увидят. Там нестандартные драйвера. В этом случае только установочный диск (флэшка) Win10 сможет помочь. Такая проблема есть например на ноутбуках Lenovo.

Comment: У меня BIOS только в UEFI работает, переключить на Legacy нельзя. Устройств всего три штуки. Даже если вынуть HDD - в биосе SSD не появляется. Но в винде в диспетчере устройств он есть. С лицензией проблем не будет, она у меня в биос вшита с завода. SSD m.2 работает через SATA3, PCI линия туда не подведена.

Comment: SSD скорее всего появится, как только на нём будет UEFI загрузчик, у меня такая же история была со вторым HDD на ноуте, для установки системы с UEFI надо грузится с установочного DVD или флешки в UEFI режиме