# Последовательная работа с группами в Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible

Прошу помочь в таком вопросе.
Для разных inventories может быть задано разное количество групп хостов, общий паттерн выглядит примерно так:

```
[GROUP_0]
host_0
host_1
...
host_m
[GROUP_1]
host_0
host_1
...
host_m
...
...
[GROUP_N]
host_0
host_1
...
host_m

[GROUP_ALL:children]
GROUP_0
GROUP_1
...
GROUP_N
```

Необходимо последовательно работать с каждой группой. Т.е. запуская playbook, передавать переменную в - hosts: GROUP_i
Сейчас, если в hosts передать GROUP_ALL, то работа происходит на всех хостах параллельно.
Я думаю, что нужно копать в сторону использования --limit GROUP_ALL[i], и указать - hosts: GROUP_ALL, но, как тогда посчитать количество элементов в GROUP_ALL?

Comment: У меня похожая проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937143/191416 и решения как-то нормального не нашлось.

Comment: Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то у вас вся загвоздка в том, что машины сгруппированы по признаку "класс". А установку нужно осуществлять одновременно только на одну машину в каждом классе. Мне кажется, что для такого подхода весь вопрос кроется в  исходной группировки хостов. Хотя, с другой стороны, я понимаю, что для других задач ваша исходная группировка может быть как раз верна.

Comment: У меня физическая группировка компьютеров и физические кабели устроены так, что по другому не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте линейную стратегию с группировкой по одному.

```
---
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  strategy: liniar

  tasks:
...
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-strategy

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понятно зачем это делать. Если linear используется по умолчанию, то зачем её явно указывать? И используя serial: 1 я не решу свою задачу. Мне нужно запускать параллельную работу на всех хостах в группе.